# Aggregate Spring Data Couchbase repository methods - how do I query for a list of all unique values for a given property?

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm having trouble figuring out how to run a pretty simple aggregate query in Spring-Data-Couchbase's repository. I'm using `org.springframework.data.spring-data-couchbase:3.2.0.RELEASE`

Let's say I have a bucket named Organism with properties like:

```
SpeciesId  SpeciesName  SpeciesDesc     OrderId  OrderDesc  ClassId  ClassDesc
1          Human        H sapiens       21       Primates   31       Mammalia
2          Chimpanzee   P troglodytes   21       Primates   31       Mammalia
3          Fruit fly    D melanogaster  22       Diptera    32       Insecta
```

I want to write a query that allows me to search for unique Orders or Classes; in SQL the queries would look like this:

```
SELECT OrderId, OrderDesc FROM Organism WHERE OrderDesc like 'Pri%' GROUP BY OrderId, OrderDesc
SELECT ClassId, ClassDesc FROM Organism WHERE ClassDesc like 'Mam%' GROUP BY ClassId, ClassDesc
```

How would I create these queries in a spring-data-couchbase repository?

---

I've tried about a thousand different things so far, but none of them have worked. First I tried adding distinct queries to the repository:

```
public interface Order {
    public Integer getOrderId();
    public String getOrderDesc();
}

@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "organism")
public interface OrganismRepository extends 
CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Organism, String> {
    Optional<List<Order>> findDistinctByOrderDescStartingWith(String orderDesc);
}
```

Next I tried using the @Query annotation:

```
//Exception - Unable to retrieve enough metadata for N1QL to entity mapping, have you selected _ID and _CAS?
@Query("SELECT orderDesc FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} WHERE orderDesc like 'Pri%' AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
Optional<List<String>> cantSelectPropertyBecauseMissingMetadata();

//Exception - Unable to execute query due to the following n1ql errors:
//   {"msg":"Expression must be a group key or aggregate: (meta(`organism`).`id`)","code":4210}
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} AND orderDesc like 'pro%' group by orderId, orderDesc")
Optional<List<Order>> selectionsMustBeIncludedInGroupByClause();

//Exception - Unable to retrieve enough metadata for N1QL to entity mapping, have you selected _ID and _CAS?
@Query("SELECT orderId, orderDesc FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} where #{#n1ql.filter} AND orderDesc like 'Pri%' group by orderId, orderDesc")
Optional<List<Order>> cantGroupByJustTwoPropsBecauseMissingMetadata();

//Exception - Unable to retrieve enough metadata for N1QL to entity mapping, have you selected _ID and _CAS?
@Query("SELECT distinct orderDesc FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} WHERE orderDesc like 'pro%' AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
Optional<List<String>> cantSelectDistinctBecauseMissingMetadata();

//Exception - Unable to execute query due to the following n1ql errors:
//  {"msg":"Expression must be a group key or aggregate: (meta(`organism`).`id`)","code":4210}
@Query("SELECT orderId, orderDesc, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).id as _ID, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).cas as _CAS FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} where #{#n1ql.filter} AND orderDesc like 'Pri%' group by orderId, orderDesc")
Optional<List<Order>> cantGroupByJustTwoPropsBecauseStillMissingMetadata();

//Exception - Unable to execute query due to the following n1ql errors:
//  {"msg":"Expression must be a group key or aggregate: (meta(`organism`).`id`)","code":4210}
@Query("SELECT orderId, orderDesc, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).id as _ID, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).cas as _CAS FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} where #{#n1ql.filter} AND orderDesc like 'Pri%' group by orderId, orderDesc, _ID, _CAS")
Optional<List<Order>> cantGroupByMETA();

@Query("SELECT distinct orderDesc, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).id as _ID, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).cas as _CAS FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} WHERE orderDesc like 'Pri%' AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
Optional<List<Order>> resultsAreNotDistinct();

@Query("SELECT distinct orderId, orderDesc, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).id as _ID, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).cas as _CAS FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} WHERE orderDesc like 'Pri%' AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
Optional<List<Order>> resultsAreNotDistinct2();

@Query("SELECT orderId, orderDesc, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).id as _ID, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).cas as _CAS FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} where #{#n1ql.filter} AND orderDesc like 'Pri%' group by orderId, orderDesc, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).id, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).cas")
Optional<List<Order>> resultsAreNotDistinct3();
```

---

The only way we've been able to get this functionality to work so far is with the `com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket` from `com.couchbase.client.java-client:2.7.9`. But I would be shocked if there isn't a way to do this in Spring-Data-Couchbase...

```
String queryString = "SELECT distinct orderId, orderDesc " + 
    "FROM `organisms` " + 
    "WHERE orderDesc LIKE $search"
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(hosts).authenticate(bucketUser, bucketPassword);
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket(bucketName);
JsonObject parameters = JsonObject.create().put("search", search);
ParameterizedN1qlQuery q = N1qlQuery.parameterized(queryString, parameters);
N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of Couchbase Spring Data will always try to get the CAS and Document id (because the metadata is important for some use cases) that is why you are getting this error.

If you need return just the attributes you need, I would recommend using a syntax similar to the following:

```
@Override
public List<KeyValueVO> listKeyValue(String companyId) {
    String bucketName = securityGroupRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().name();
    String queryString = "SELECT meta().id as id, name FROM "+bucketName+
            " WHERE  _class = '"+SecurityGroup.class.getName() +"' and removed = false and companyId = '"+companyId+"' order by name ";
    N1qlParams params = N1qlParams.build().consistency(ScanConsistency.NOT_BOUNDED).adhoc(true);
    ParameterizedN1qlQuery query = N1qlQuery.parameterized(queryString, JsonObject.create(), params);
    return securityGroupRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().findByN1QLProjection(query, KeyValueVO.class);

}
```

PS: Yes, I should use ParameterizedN1qlQuery properly instead of concat the parameters in the string, but you got the idea.

Comment: I'm surprised spring-data-couchbase requires the inclusion of `id` and `cas` in every query - couchbase clearly supports aggregate queries like `group by`, so it seems pretty short sighted of them not to support that in their library.

Sorry, I know my question was pretty wordy, but I'm not looking for just part of the documents - I can achieve that with Spring projections. Selecting ID and name wouldn't give me a list of distinct names would it?